# How can I use alias of field insteed of field name in ArcGIS silverlight API?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-server, arcgis-silverlight-api

I developed a webgis using ArcGIS silverlight API . I'm using ArcGIS 10 and silverlight API 3.1 .I want to show alias name insteed of field name of a feature class. How can i use alias names in my webgis?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an "Alias" property on the Field class. That should solve your issue.

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/silverlight-api/apiref/api_start.htm?ESRI.ArcGIS.Client~ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Field~Alias.html

HTH,
Kiran.